# Calabash Android run error: The first parameter must be the path to the apk file

Tags: calabash-android

I am trying to run sample calabash-android test. But I am facing the below error.

> C:\Ruby23\TMSampleAndroid-master>calabash-android run TestmunkTest_debug.apk --verbose
>   The first parameter must be the path to the apk file.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

- Separate the project directory from your Ruby23 installation by moving the calabash project inside a Workspace folder for example.
- Create a folder to hold your .apk inside the calabash project, for example "APKFile"
- In the run command specify the full path to the .apk file and see if it runs, like this:

> calabash-android run
>   C:\Ruby23\TMSampleAndroid-master\TestmunkTest_debug.apk

or for my example:

> calabash-android run
>   C:\Workspace\TMSampleAndroid-master\TestmunkTest_debug.apk

To add logging write "--verbose" after the command. The error that you get might be because of the typo "--v erbose"